# Alter a column with data to an existing table

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an SQL table illustrated below but with much more rows (around 500):

Current Table

```
+----------------+--------+
|   EmployeeID   |  EMP   |
+----------------+--------+
|       01       |  val   |
+----------------+--------+
|       02       |  val   |
+----------------+--------+
|       03       |  val   |
+----------------+--------+
|       04       |  val   |
+----------------+--------+
```

and an following Excel sheet with the same data except the additional OtherID column:

Excel Sheet

```
+------------+----------------+--------+
|  OtherID   |   EmployeeID   |  EMP   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
|    001     |       01       |  val   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
|    002     |       02       |  val   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
|    003     |       03       |  val   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
|    004     |       04       |  val   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
```

How can I update the original table (without deleting and creating a new one) by adding the missing OtherID column and make sure that the OutherID is related to the EmployeeID?

Desired result in SQL

```
+------------+----------------+--------+
|  OtherID   |   EmployeeID   |  EMP   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
|    001     |       01       |  val   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
|    002     |       02       |  val   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
|    003     |       03       |  val   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
|    004     |       04       |  val   |
+------------+----------------+--------+
```

Thanks.

Comment: Load the excel sheet into sql server as table. And make join over original and loaded table with employeeid. Then do an update operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Insert Excel Sheet Data to Dummy Table. (ex: `BulkInsert`)

2) Use the next code:

```
Alter table Originaltable
ADD OtherID datatype;
go

UPDATE Originaltable
   SET Originaltable.OtherID   = DummyTable.OtherID   
   FROM OriginaltableINNER JOIN  DummyTable
   ON Originaltable.id = DummyTable.id
```